# qrencode: invalid argument

Tags: php, qr-code, encode

I try to generate QR code to show it on the site. The command is:

```
qrencode -o MkFZwNmTQv.png -s 2 -l L < MkFZwNmTQv.msg
```

It worked fine but now MkFZwNmTQv.msg has new content and with this content I get an error:

```
Failed to encode the input data:: Invalid argument
```

I cannot understand what's wrong with that content.

Comment: Have you tried without `<`?

Comment: Yes, but in this case I get QR code for the string "MkFZwNmTQv.msg" but not for the content in the file.

Comment: Why is it tagged `php`?